# Will chat rooms be indexed by Google?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

I would like to see chat rooms indexed by search engines. To make this possible, the 'load older messages' button at the top of chat rooms would need to work without JavaScript, or else the chat room page should show all messages if JavaScript is not enabled.

Comment: what does this have to do with SO? do we have chat rooms now? oh wait, i see that we do http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/third-place-chat-beta-preview/

Comment: the [transcript](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/chats/transcripts/14) doesn't need JavaScript

Comment: Oh my. So the chat site *is* going to become the number one Google hit for Duck.... organs.

Comment: @Pekka: that place is kept by [another page](http://www.find-me-a-gift.co.uk/duck-with-a-dick.html)

Comment: @Pekka [No, not really](https://www.google.com/search?q=duck+organs&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb).

Answer (score 16):

I sure would like them **not** to be indexed by search engines.

This is a chat, it's half informal, why would you want that indexed by Google? Questions and answers, ok, that's the whole point, it brings answers to people searching. But chats? I don't see how it would be useful to the world.

It's like comments under questions and answers. They don't bring value which would be interesting to index on a search engine, and as such, are explicitly advising them to not index them (if I understood the whole "nofollow" thing).

Comment: IRC in 2010, baby.

Comment: Good point. In that case it might be a good idea to let users know.

Comment: Chat can't be a secret _forever_ you know.

Comment: The word's going to get out to the world soon and the throngs will be pouring in to expect a better-experts-exchange : insta-SOUFM-answers! (shudder) (Want your insta-answers? Come to SO-chat and just-add-reputation, 20 to be precise)

Comment: Interesting, it may not be indexed by Google, but all content is licensed under cc-wiki, and dumps will be made available. So anything you say on chat will be public, just not quite as prominent as if it was indexed by Google.

Comment: @Liam - comments I make under questions and answers are public too, and in cc-wiki as well. They are not indexed by search engines anyway. I agree that I go too far on the "privacy" issue, the main point is more about indexing, since it doesn't really have a value. It's still publicly available, though.

Comment: I agree.  I'm not very comfortable with the situation myself.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, they will be indexed. They are public by default.

(you can't *talk* in a room unless you have 20 rep on the parent site, but you can *listen* as much as you want)